# Por qué el menú siempre queda mas abajo?

Tags: css3

Tengo un **menú** escrito en `HTML` y `CSS3`, el problema es que este SIEMPRE queda como si tuviera `padding` o `top`, **por qué ocurre esto y como arreglarlo**?

```css
#menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: monospace;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 600;
}
#menu ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: gray;
 display: table;
 width: 101%;
}
#menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: gray;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

#menu > li {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100%/3);
}
#menu a:hover {
  background-color: green;
  transition: .8s;
}
#menu li ul {
  display: none;
}
#menu li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  transition: 1s;
}


#menu li {
  line-height: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

#menu li ul {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: black;">
<nav>
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
<li><a href="cp.html">Computación</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="js.html">Javascript</a>
<li><a href="fp.html">Fundamentos</a>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="cp.html">Acerca</a>
<ul> 
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionarlo debes quitar los margenes que agrega el navegador por defecto, basicamente resetear los margenes:

- A `body`, indicarle `margin:0;`, de esta manera quitas el `margin:8px` que trae.
- Al primer elento, en este caso `#menu`, indicarle `margin:0;`. Esto por que? Porque si te fijas en los margenes computados que tiene te encontraras esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Margenes de 16px que debes remover.

```css
#menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: monospace;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 600;
}
#menu ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: gray;
 display: table;
 width: 101%;
}
#menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: gray;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  margin:0;
}

#menu > li {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100%/3);
}
#menu a:hover {
  background-color: green;
  transition: .8s;
}
#menu li ul {
  display: none;
}
#menu li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  transition: 1s;
}


#menu li {
  line-height: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

#menu li ul {
  position: absolute;
}


body {    
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: black;">
<nav>
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
<li><a href="cp.html">Computación</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="js.html">Javascript</a>
<li><a href="fp.html">Fundamentos</a>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="cp.html">Acerca</a>
<ul> 
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

De ejecutar tu script, veo que tiene margenes el `body`, y el `ul` que está debajo del nav.

Los podes quitar con css.

```
ul, body{
  margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Los navegadores colocan márgenes por defectos a los elementos, yo te recomiendo que siempre al inicio de tu css formatees esas márgenes utilizando el selector universal:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Por defecto, los navegadores inyectan los documentos con *estilos predeterminados*; estos estilos pueden afectar la manera en que se visualiza un sitio dependiendo del navegador. Para evitar esto lo que se debe hacer es un **reset**.

La manera más sencilla es mediante:

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

La otra opción es usar la librería [normalize](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.min.css) que es bastante más compleja y que hace esto de manera más óptima.

**Ejemplo**

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: monospace;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 600;
}
#menu ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: gray;
 display: table;
 width: 101%;
}
#menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: gray;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

#menu > li {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100%/3);
}
#menu a:hover {
  background-color: green;
  transition: .8s;
}
#menu li ul {
  display: none;
}
#menu li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  transition: 1s;
}


#menu li {
  line-height: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

#menu li ul {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: black;">
<nav>
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
<li><a href="cp.html">Computación</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="js.html">Javascript</a>
<li><a href="fp.html">Fundamentos</a>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="cp.html">Acerca</a>
<ul> 
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```